# Mock with Query Builder

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have created project where I have repository and query repository. Query() method in every repository return IQueryBuilder to do things.

I have method as below in User class:

```
public class User
{
   //...

   public async Task<State> GetCurrentState(IEventRepository entRepository)
        {
             var lastWorkdayWeekEvents = await eventRepository.Query()
                .ByUserId(this.Id).ByDateTimeRange(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3), 
                         DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)).FilterAutomatic().               
             ToListAsync();

             //return ...
        }
}
```

I would like to test this method. I was thining to use Moq. I would like to mock ToListAsync() method.

```
    [Fact]
            public async void GetCurrentState()
            {
                //arrage
                var lastEvents = new Task<List<Event>>(() => new List<Event>
                {
                    new Event{ActivityId = ActivityId.BoxesIn, Address =  new Address{Id = 99}}
                });

                var eventRepository = new Mock<IEventRepository>().Object;
                var eventQueryBuilder = new Mock<IEventQueryBuilder>().Setup(x => x.ToListAsync()).Returns(() => lastEvents);

                var user = new User();
                var result = await user.GetCurrentState(eventRepository);
                //...

}
```

I am getting null reference because eventRepository.Query() returns null. Do I have to mock all return methods from QueryRepository to make it works? How do I make it works without so much work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Moq provide method SetReturnsDefault(). So the solution is

> eventQueryBuilder.SetReturnsDefault(eventQueryBuilder.Object);

Answer (score 1):

I guess methods (ByUserId, ByDateTimeRange, FilterAutomatic, ToListAsync)
are extension methods e.g. 
IQuerable ByUserId(this IQuerable events); If it is true you can mock only .Query() method returning something like this:
new List {... you data... }.AsQuerable();